# How to generate a class in Dotty with macro?

Tags: scala, annotations, metaprogramming, scala-macros, scala-3

Is it possible to generate a new class with macro in Dotty, Scala 3 ?

Zlaja

Comment: Macros were never meant for creating totally new types (classes including). At best you could create a macro-generated instance of a class tuned for some arguments. I think macro annotations and/or compiler plugins could be used to insert new class body into companion object of annotated class (not a good idea), but that's it. If you want to generate classes use a code generator instead.

Comment: For @main annotation in Dotty I find only class: main extends scala.annotation.Annotation {} in source code. So, does macro annotation need compiler plugin to work?

Comment: @zlaja `@main` is not a macro annotation, it's individual annotation managed by Dotty compiler. Currently you can't create such custom annotation without compiler plugin to Dotty.

Comment: @zlaja I updated my answer with examples of macro annotations to be added in Scala 3.3.0

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Currently in Dotty there is only (kind of) [*def* macros](http://dotty.epfl.ch/docs/reference/metaprogramming/macros.html). Currently there is no (kind of) [macro annotations](https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/macros/annotations.html), which could generate a new member, new class etc.

For generation of a new member, new class etc. you can use

- [Scalameta](https://scalameta.org/) (without or with [SemanticDB](https://scalameta.org/docs/semanticdb/guide.html), [Scalafix](https://scalacenter.github.io/scalafix/docs/developers/setup.html) [[see also](https://github.com/olafurpg/scalafix-codegen)] depending on whether such generation is [just syntactic or semantic](https://scalacenter.github.io/scalafix/docs/developers/before-you-begin.html#is-your-rule-syntactic-or-semantic)), which works at the time before compile time (source generation), or
- a [compiler plugin](http://dotty.epfl.ch/docs/reference/changed-features/compiler-plugins.html), which works at compile time.

Let me remind you that even in Scalac the ability to generate a new member, new class etc. also appeared not from the very beginning. Such functionality (macro annotations) appeared as [Macro Paradise](https://github.com/scalamacros/paradise) compiler plugin to Scalac.

I can't exclude that somewhen somebody will write something like Macro Paradise for Dotty. It's too early for that, it's only feature-freeze for Dotty now, even language syntax ([for example](https://github.com/lampepfl/dotty/pull/7794)) and standard library keep changing now (there is also [list of libraries](https://github.com/lampepfl/dotty/tree/master/community-build/community-projects) that are testing their ability to work with Dotty, for example currently no Scalaz/Cats are there).

---

For example, while in Scala 2 [Simulacrum](https://github.com/typelevel/simulacrum) was using macro annotations, in Scala 3 Simulacrum-Scalafix is implemented as Scalafix rules

https://github.com/typelevel/simulacrum-scalafix

https://index.scala-lang.org/typelevel/simulacrum-scalafix/simulacrum-scalafix/0.5.0?target=_2.12

One more use case: Breeze uses sbt plugin and Scalameta for source code generation

https://github.com/scalanlp/breeze

https://github.com/scalanlp/breeze/blob/master/DEVELOP.md

https://github.com/dlwh/sbt-breeze-expand-codegen

---

**Update.** We can now generate an **inner** class with Scala 3 (*def*) macros: [Method Override with Scala 3 Macros](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68550985/method-override-with-scala-3-macros)

---

**Update (March 2023).** Starting from Scala 3.3.0-RC2, there appeared macro annotations (implemented by Nicolas Stucki).

https://github.com/lampepfl/dotty/releases/tag/3.3.0-RC2 ([discussion](https://contributors.scala-lang.org/t/3-3-0-release-thread/6079))

*[Proof of Concept] Code generation via rewriting errors in macro annotations* https://github.com/lampepfl/dotty/pull/16545

*Zhendong Ang. Macro Annotations for Scala 3 (master thesis)* https://infoscience.epfl.ch/record/294615

*Macro annotation (part 1)* https://github.com/lampepfl/dotty/pull/16392

*Macro annotations class modifications (part 2)* https://github.com/lampepfl/dotty/pull/16454

*Enable returning classes from MacroAnnotations (part 3)* https://github.com/lampepfl/dotty/pull/16534

**New definitions are not visible from outside the macro expansion.**

*build.sbt*

```
scalaVersion := "3.3.0-RC3"
```

Here is an example. Macro annotation `@genObj` generates a companion object with `given tc: TC[A] = new TC[A]`, `@modifyObj` modifies the companion object generating `given tc: TC[A] = new TC[A]` inside:

```
import scala.annotation.{MacroAnnotation, experimental}
import scala.quoted.*

object Macros:
  class TC[T]

  @experimental
  class genObj extends MacroAnnotation:
    def transform(using Quotes)(tree: quotes.reflect.Definition): List[quotes.reflect.Definition] =
      import quotes.reflect.*
      tree match
        case ClassDef(className, _, _, _, _) =>
          val modParents = List(TypeTree.of[Object])

          val tpe = TypeRepr.of[TC].appliedTo(List(tree.symbol.typeRef))

          def decls(cls: Symbol): List[Symbol] = List(
            Symbol.newVal(cls, "tc", tpe, Flags.Given, Symbol.noSymbol)
          )

          val mod = Symbol.newModule(Symbol.spliceOwner, className, Flags.EmptyFlags, Flags.EmptyFlags,
            modParents.map(_.tpe), decls, Symbol.noSymbol)
          val cls = mod.moduleClass
          val tcSym = cls.declaredField("tc")
          val tcDef = tpe.asType match
            case '[TC[t]] => ValDef(tcSym, Some('{new TC[t]}.asTerm))
          val (modValDef, modClsDef) = ClassDef.module(mod, modParents, body = List(tcDef))

          val res = List(tree, modValDef, modClsDef)
          println(res.map(_.show))
          res
        case _ =>
          report.errorAndAbort("@genObj can annotate only classes")

  @experimental
  class modifyObj extends MacroAnnotation:
    def transform(using Quotes)(tree: quotes.reflect.Definition): List[quotes.reflect.Definition] =
      import quotes.reflect.*
      tree match
        case ClassDef(name, constr, parents, selfOpt, body) =>

          val tpe = TypeRepr.of[TC].appliedTo(List(tree.symbol.companionClass.typeRef))

          val tcSym = Symbol.newVal(tree.symbol, "tc", tpe, Flags.Given, Symbol.noSymbol)
          val tcDef = tpe.asType match
            case '[TC[t]] => ValDef(tcSym, Some('{ new TC[t] }.asTerm))

          val res = List(ClassDef.copy(tree)(name, constr, parents, selfOpt, body :+ tcDef))
          println(res.map(_.show))
          res
        case _ =>
          report.errorAndAbort("@modifyObj can annotate only classes")
```

```
import Macros.{TC, genObj, modifyObj}
import scala.annotation.experimental

@experimental
object App:
  @genObj
  class A

//scalac: List(@Macros.genObj class A(),
//lazy val A: App.A.type = new App.A(),
//object A extends java.lang.Object { this: App.A.type =>
//  val tc: Macros.TC[App.A] = new Macros.TC[App.A]()
//})
```

```
import Macros.{TC, genObj, modifyObj}
import scala.annotation.experimental

@experimental
object App:
  class A

  @modifyObj
  object A

//scalac: List(@Macros.modifyObj object A {
//  val tc: Macros.TC[App.A] = new Macros.TC[App.A]()
//})
```

[Macro Annotations in Scala 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67770927/macro-annotations-in-scala-3)

[How to generate parameterless constructor at compile time using scala 3 macro?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75159088/how-to-generate-parameterless-constructor-at-compile-time-using-scala-3-macro)

[Scala 3 macro to create enum](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69227772/scala-3-macro-to-create-enum)

Comment: But Scalameta does not (yet?) support Scala3?

Comment: @ecoe Scalameta does support Scala 3. You can use Scalameta in order to read/analyze/transform/generate Scala 3 code https://scastie.scala-lang.org/DmytroMitin/T0tFbxxgROGn0lUbHMbUBQ/1 Scalameta just **runs** in Scala 2.

Comment: @ecoe Actually, Scalameta not only handles Scala 3 code, it even runs in Scala 3 (because of Scala 2 - Scala 3 [interop](https://docs.scala-lang.org/scala3/guides/migration/compatibility-intro.html)). You just can't use Scala 2 macros e.g. `q"..."` interpolator https://scastie.scala-lang.org/DmytroMitin/XZHWRGUiRYmpuSnKB1rrqQ `libraryDependencies += "org.scalameta" %% "scalameta" % "4.5.13" cross CrossVersion.for3Use2_13`

Comment: https://contributors.scala-lang.org/t/pre-sip-export-macros/6168 https://github.com/littlenag/dotty/tree/export-macro https://gist.github.com/littlenag/d0c9dfddeb9002684c6effef18c2ec5e

Comment: WIth the `@experimental` annotation, we can hardly use this in library code. It make the whole code base become a experimental scope. 
Is there some workaround?

Answer (score 7):

You can make a [transparent](https://dotty.epfl.ch/docs/reference/metaprogramming/macros.html#relationship-with-transparent-inline) macro that returns a [structural type](https://dotty.epfl.ch/docs/reference/changed-features/structural-types.html) to generate types with any `val`s and `def`s that you wish.

Here is an example; method `props`, when called with a Product type, creates an object with the first Product element name as a String `val`.

```scala
case class User(firstName: String, age: Int)

// has the type of Props { val firstName: String }
val userProps = props[User]

println(userProps.firstName) // prints "prop for firstName"
println(userProps.lastName) // compile error
```

And the implementation, which is a little tricky but not too bad:

```scala
import scala.compiletime.*
import scala.quoted.*
import scala.deriving.Mirror

class Props extends Selectable:
  def selectDynamic(name: String): Any =
    "prop for " + name

transparent inline def props[T] =
  ${ propsImpl[T] }

private def propsImpl[T: Type](using Quotes): Expr[Any] =
  import quotes.reflect.*

  Expr.summon[Mirror.ProductOf[T]].get match
    case '{ $m: Mirror.ProductOf[T] {type MirroredElemLabels = mels; type MirroredElemTypes = mets } } =>
      Type.of[mels] match
        case '[mel *: melTail] =>
          val label = Type.valueOfConstant[mel].get.toString

          Refinement(TypeRepr.of[Props], label, TypeRepr.of[String]).asType match
            case '[tpe] =>
              val res = '{
                val p = Props()
                p.asInstanceOf[tpe]
              }
              println(res.show)
              res
```

Using recursion, you can refine the Refinement (since Refinement <: TypeRepr) until everything is built out.

With that said, using `transparent inline` or even Scala 2 macro annotations to generate new types makes it very hard for IDEs to support auto-completion. So if possible, I recommend using the standard [Typeclass derivation](https://dotty.epfl.ch/docs/reference/contextual/derivation.html).

You can even derive default behavior for standard traits:

```
trait SpringDataRepository[E, Id]:
  def findAll(): Seq[E]

trait DerivedSpringDataRepository[E: Mirror.ProductOf, Id]:
  def findAll(): Seq[E] = findAllDefault[E, Id]()
  
private inline def findAllDefault[E, Id](using m: Mirror.ProductOf[E]): Seq[E] =
  findAllDefaultImpl[E, m.MirroredLabel, m.MirroredElemLabels]()

private inline def findAllDefaultImpl[E, Ml, Mels](columns: ArrayBuffer[String] = ArrayBuffer()): Seq[E] =
  inline erasedValue[Mels] match
    case _: EmptyTuple =>
      // base case
      println("executing.. select " + columns.mkString(", ") + " from " + constValue[Ml])
      Seq.empty[E]
    case _: (mel *: melTail) =>
      findAllDefaultImpl[E, Ml, melTail](columns += constValue[mel].toString)
```

Then, all a user has to do is extend `DerivedSpringDataRepository` with their Product type:

```scala
case class User(id: Int, first: String, last: String)

class UserRepo extends DerivedSpringDataRepository[User, Int]

val userRepo = UserRepo()

userRepo.findAll() // prints "executing.. select id, first, last from User"
```