# Macro Annotations in Scala 3

Tags: scala, scala-macros, scala-3, scala-macro-paradise

The following is a quote from [Macros: the Plan for Scala 3](https://www.scala-lang.org/blog/2018/04/30/in-a-nutshell.html) from more than 3 years ago:

> For instance, one will be able to define a macro annotation @json that adds a JSON serializer to a type.

Any idea how/if this is actually possible in Scala 3?

More generally, is there anything in Scala 3 that can provide "Macro Annotations" functionality?
The following is a quote from [Macro Annotations - Scala 2.13](https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/macros/annotations.html):

> Unlike in the previous versions of macro paradise, macro annotations in 2.0 are done right in the sense that they: 1) apply not just to classes and objects, but to arbitrary definitions, 2) **allow expansions of classes to modify or even create companion objects**

Comment: I submitted an answer with examples of macro annotations to be added in Scala 3.3.0

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As of June 2021, *macro annotations are not supported in Scala 3*, and they are not mentioned anywhere in the doc.

Right now, if you'd like to generate methods, classes or objects, I believe you have to use scalameta or write a compiler plugin.

Obviously, this situation might change in the future, macro annotations were not part of Scala 2 at the beginning either.

Answer (score 9):

Starting from Scala 3.3.0-RC2, there appeared macro annotations (implemented by Nicolas Stucki).

*Macro annotation (part 1)* https://github.com/lampepfl/dotty/pull/16392

*Macro annotations class modifications (part 2)* https://github.com/lampepfl/dotty/pull/16454

*Enable returning classes from MacroAnnotations (part 3)* https://github.com/lampepfl/dotty/pull/16534

**New definitions are not visible from outside the macro expansion.**

---

*build.sbt*

```
scalaVersion := "3.3.0-RC3"
```

Several examples:

- Macro annotation `@memoize` adds memoization to a method

```
import scala.annotation.{MacroAnnotation, experimental}
import scala.collection.mutable
import scala.quoted.*

object Macros:
  @experimental
  class memoize extends MacroAnnotation:
    def transform(using Quotes)(tree: quotes.reflect.Definition): List[quotes.reflect.Definition] =
      import quotes.reflect.*
      tree match
        case DefDef(name, TermParamClause(param :: Nil) :: Nil, tpt, Some(rhsTree)) =>
          (Ref(param.symbol).asExpr, rhsTree.asExpr) match
            case ('{ $paramRefExpr: t }, '{ $rhsExpr: u }) =>
              val cacheTpe = TypeRepr.of[mutable.Map[t, u]]
              val cacheSymbol = Symbol.newVal(tree.symbol.owner, name + "Cache", cacheTpe, Flags.Private, Symbol.noSymbol)
              val cacheRhs = '{ mutable.Map.empty[t, u] }.asTerm
              val cacheVal = ValDef(cacheSymbol, Some(cacheRhs))
              val cacheRefExpr = Ref(cacheSymbol).asExprOf[mutable.Map[t, u]]
              val newRhs = '{ $cacheRefExpr.getOrElseUpdate($paramRefExpr, $rhsExpr) }.asTerm
              val newTree = DefDef.copy(tree)(name, TermParamClause(param :: Nil) :: Nil, tpt, Some(newRhs))
              val res = List(cacheVal, newTree)
              println(res.map(_.show))
              res
        case _ =>
          report.error("Annotation only supported on `def` with a single argument are supported")
          List(tree)
```

```
import scala.annotation.experimental
import Macros.memoize

@experimental
object App:
  @memoize
  def fib(n: Int): Int =
    println(s"compute fib of $n")
    if n <= 1 then n else fib(n - 1) + fib(n - 2)

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit =
    println(fib(5))

//scalac: List(val fibCache: scala.collection.mutable.Map[n, scala.Int] = scala.collection.mutable.Map.empty[n.type, scala.Int],
// @Macros.memoize def fib(n: scala.Int): scala.Int = App.fibCache.getOrElseUpdate(n, {
//  scala.Predef.println(_root_.scala.StringContext.apply("compute fib of ", "").s(n))
//  if (n.<=(1)) n else App.fib(n.-(1)).+(App.fib(n.-(2)))
//}))

//compute fib of 5
//compute fib of 4
//compute fib of 3
//compute fib of 2
//compute fib of 1
//compute fib of 0
//5
```

- Macro annotation `@equals` generates methods `equals` and `hashCode` in a class

```
import scala.annotation.{MacroAnnotation, experimental}
import scala.quoted.*

object Macros:
  @experimental
  class equals extends MacroAnnotation:
    def transform(using Quotes)(tree: quotes.reflect.Definition): List[quotes.reflect.Definition] =
      import quotes.reflect.*
      tree match
        case ClassDef(className, ctr, parents, self, body) =>
          val cls = tree.symbol

          val constructorParameters = ctr.paramss.collect { case clause: TermParamClause => clause }
          if constructorParameters.size != 1 || constructorParameters.head.params.isEmpty then
            report.errorAndAbort("@equals class must have a single argument list with at least one argument", ctr.pos)

          def checkNotOverridden(sym: Symbol): Unit =
            if sym.overridingSymbol(cls).exists then
              report.error(s"Cannot override ${sym.name} in a @equals class")

          val fields = body.collect {
            case vdef: ValDef if vdef.symbol.flags.is(Flags.ParamAccessor) =>
              Select(This(cls), vdef.symbol).asExpr
          }

          val equalsSym = Symbol.requiredMethod("java.lang.Object.equals")
          checkNotOverridden(equalsSym)
          val equalsOverrideSym = Symbol.newMethod(cls, "equals", equalsSym.info, Flags.Override, Symbol.noSymbol)

          def equalsOverrideDefBody(argss: List[List[Tree]]): Option[Term] =
            given Quotes = equalsOverrideSym.asQuotes

            cls.typeRef.asType match
              case '[c] =>
                Some(equalsExpr[c](argss.head.head.asExpr, fields).asTerm)

          val equalsOverrideDef = DefDef(equalsOverrideSym, equalsOverrideDefBody)

          val hashSym = Symbol.newVal(cls, Symbol.freshName("hash"), TypeRepr.of[Int], Flags.Private | Flags.Lazy, Symbol.noSymbol)
          val hashVal = ValDef(hashSym, Some(hashCodeExpr(className, fields)(using hashSym.asQuotes).asTerm))

          val hashCodeSym = Symbol.requiredMethod("java.lang.Object.hashCode")
          checkNotOverridden(hashCodeSym)
          val hashCodeOverrideSym = Symbol.newMethod(cls, "hashCode", hashCodeSym.info, Flags.Override, Symbol.noSymbol)
          val hashCodeOverrideDef = DefDef(hashCodeOverrideSym, _ => Some(Ref(hashSym)))

          val newBody = equalsOverrideDef :: hashVal :: hashCodeOverrideDef :: body
          val res = List(ClassDef.copy(tree)(className, ctr, parents, self, newBody))
          println(res.map(_.show))
          res
        case _ =>
          report.error("Annotation only supports `class`")
          List(tree)

    private def equalsExpr[T: Type](that: Expr[Any], thisFields: List[Expr[Any]])(using Quotes): Expr[Boolean] =
      '{
        $that match
          case that: T@unchecked =>
            ${
              val thatFields: List[Expr[Any]] =
                import quotes.reflect.*
                thisFields.map(field => Select('{ that }.asTerm, field.asTerm.symbol).asExpr)
              thisFields.zip(thatFields)
                .map { case (thisField, thatField) => '{ $thisField == $thatField } }
                .reduce { case (pred1, pred2) => '{ $pred1 && $pred2 } }
            }
          case _ => false
      }

    private def hashCodeExpr(className: String, thisFields: List[Expr[Any]])(using Quotes): Expr[Int] =
      '{
        var acc: Int = ${ Expr(scala.runtime.Statics.mix(-889275714, className.hashCode)) }
        ${
          Expr.block(
            thisFields.map {
              case '{ $field: Boolean } => '{ if $field then 1231 else 1237 }
              case '{ $field: Byte } => '{ $field.toInt }
              case '{ $field: Char } => '{ $field.toInt }
              case '{ $field: Short } => '{ $field.toInt }
              case '{ $field: Int } => field
              case '{ $field: Long } => '{ scala.runtime.Statics.longHash($field) }
              case '{ $field: Double } => '{ scala.runtime.Statics.doubleHash($field) }
              case '{ $field: Float } => '{ scala.runtime.Statics.floatHash($field) }
              case '{ $field: Null } => '{ 0 }
              case '{ $field: Unit } => '{ 0 }
              case field => '{ scala.runtime.Statics.anyHash($field) }
            }.map(hash => '{ acc = scala.runtime.Statics.mix(acc, $hash) }),
            '{ scala.runtime.Statics.finalizeHash(acc, ${ Expr(thisFields.size) }) }
          )
        }
      }
```

```
import scala.annotation.experimental
import Macros.equals

@experimental
object App:
  @equals
  class User(val name: String, val id: Int)

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit =
    println(User("a", 1) == User("a", 1)) // true

//scalac: List(@Macros.equals class User(val name: scala.Predef.String, val id: scala.Int) {
//  override def equals(x$0: scala.Any): scala.Boolean = x$0 match {
//    case that: App.User @scala.unchecked =>
//      User.this.name.==(that.name).&&(User.this.id.==(that.id))
//    case _ =>
//      false
//  }
//  lazy val hash$macro$1: scala.Int = {
//    var acc: scala.Int = 515782504
//    acc = scala.runtime.Statics.mix(acc, scala.runtime.Statics.anyHash(User.this.name))
//    acc = scala.runtime.Statics.mix(acc, User.this.id)
//    scala.runtime.Statics.finalizeHash(acc, 2)
//  }
//  override def hashCode(): scala.Int = User.this.hash$macro$1
//})
```

- Macro annotation `@addClass` generates a class near a method

```
import scala.annotation.{MacroAnnotation, experimental}
import scala.quoted.*

object Macros:
  @experimental
  class addClass extends MacroAnnotation:
    def transform(using Quotes)(tree: quotes.reflect.Definition): List[quotes.reflect.Definition] =
      import quotes.reflect._
      tree match
        case DefDef(name, List(TermParamClause(Nil)), tpt, Some(rhs)) =>
          val parents = List(TypeTree.of[Object])
          def decls(cls: Symbol): List[Symbol] =
            List(Symbol.newMethod(cls, "run", MethodType(Nil)(_ => Nil, _ => TypeRepr.of[Unit]), Flags.EmptyFlags, Symbol.noSymbol))

          val newClassName = Symbol.freshName("Bar")
          val cls = Symbol.newClass(Symbol.spliceOwner/*.owner*/, newClassName, parents = parents.map(_.tpe), decls, selfType = None)
          val runSym = cls.declaredMethod("run").head

          val runDef = DefDef(runSym, _ => Some(rhs))
          val clsDef = ClassDef(cls, parents, body = List(runDef))

          val newCls = Apply(Select(New(TypeIdent(cls)), cls.primaryConstructor), Nil)

          val newDef = DefDef.copy(tree)(name, List(TermParamClause(Nil)), tpt, Some(Apply(Select(newCls, runSym), Nil)))
          val res = List(clsDef, newDef)
          println(res.map(_.show))
          res
        case _ =>
          report.error("Annotation only supports `def` with one argument")
          List(tree)
```

```
import Macros.addClass

import scala.annotation.experimental

object App:
  @addClass @experimental
  def bar(): Unit = println("bar")

//List(class Bar$macro$1 extends java.lang.Object {
//  def run(): scala.Unit = scala.Predef.println("bar")
//}, @scala.annotation.experimental @Macros.addClass def bar(): scala.Unit = new App.Bar$macro$1().run())
```

- Macro annotation `@mainMacro` transforms a method into an object with runnable method `main`

```
import scala.annotation.{experimental, MacroAnnotation}
import scala.quoted._
import scala.collection.mutable

object Macros:
  @experimental
  class mainMacro extends MacroAnnotation:
    def transform(using Quotes)(tree: quotes.reflect.Definition): List[quotes.reflect.Definition] =
      import quotes.reflect._
      tree match
        case DefDef(name, List(TermParamClause(Nil)), _, _) =>
          val parents = List(TypeTree.of[Object])
          def decls(cls: Symbol): List[Symbol] =
            List(Symbol.newMethod(cls, "main", MethodType(List("args"))(_ => List(TypeRepr.of[Array[String]]), _ => TypeRepr.of[Unit]), Flags.Static, Symbol.noSymbol))

          val cls = Symbol.newClass(Symbol.spliceOwner, name, parents = parents.map(_.tpe), decls, selfType = None)
          val mainSym = cls.declaredMethod("main").head

          val mainDef = DefDef(mainSym, _ => Some(Apply(Ref(tree.symbol), Nil)))
          val clsDef = ClassDef(cls, parents, body = List(mainDef))

          val res = List(clsDef, tree)
          println(res.map(_.show))
          res

        case _ =>
          report.error("Annotation only supports `def` without arguments")
          List(tree)
```

```
import Macros.mainMacro
import scala.annotation.experimental

@experimental
object App:
  @mainMacro def Test(): Unit = println("macro generated main")

//scalac: List(class Test extends java.lang.Object {
//  def main(args: scala.Array[scala.Predef.String]): scala.Unit = App.Test()
//}, @Macros.mainMacro def Test(): scala.Unit = scala.Predef.println("macro generated main"))
```

https://github.com/lampepfl/dotty/blob/3.3.0-RC3/library/src/scala/annotation/MacroAnnotation.scala

[How to generate a class in Dotty with macro?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59473523/how-to-generate-a-class-in-dotty-with-macro)

[How to generate parameterless constructor at compile time using scala 3 macro?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75159088/how-to-generate-parameterless-constructor-at-compile-time-using-scala-3-macro)

[Scala 3 macro to create enum](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69227772/scala-3-macro-to-create-enum)

https://users.scala-lang.org/t/macro-annotations-replacement-in-scala-3/7374

https://contributors.scala-lang.org/t/sponsoring-work-on-scala-3-macro-annotations/5658

https://contributors.scala-lang.org/t/scala-3-macro-annotations-and-code-generation/6035

https://contributors.scala-lang.org/t/scala-3-macros-next-steps/6105

https://contributors.scala-lang.org/t/whitebox-macros-in-scala-3-are-possible-after-all/5014

Comment: https://contributors.scala-lang.org/t/pre-sip-export-macros/6168 https://github.com/littlenag/dotty/tree/export-macro https://gist.github.com/littlenag/d0c9dfddeb9002684c6effef18c2ec5e

Comment: I wasn't able to get these working with sbt due to "Failed to find name hashes" - Details: https://github.com/sbt/sbt/issues/7157