# How to generate parameterless constructor at compile time using scala 3 macro?

Tags: scala, metaprogramming, scala-macros, scala-3

how to generate a private parameterless constructor on a class (at compile time) when it annotated with `@entity`
annotation - in scala 3 macros

`class entity extends scala.annotation.StaticAnnotation`

```
@entity
class Student(val id: Long, val name: String) {
  //??? at compile time generates: private def this() = this(0, null)
}
```

Comment: Scala 3 macros are `def` macros, not annotations. You can't *generate* code with them. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67770927/macro-annotations-in-scala-3 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59473523/how-to-generate-a-class-in-dotty-with-macro https://contributors.scala-lang.org/t/scala-3-macro-annotations-and-code-generation/6035 https://users.scala-lang.org/t/macro-annotations-replacement-in-scala-3/7374

Comment: You can generate code at pre-compile time with Scalameta/SemanticDB/Scalafix or at compile time with compiler plugin.

Comment: Macro annotations in Scala 3 can be considered WIP at the moment (see: https://contributors.scala-lang.org/t/scala-3-macro-annotations-and-code-generation/6035) but they aren't released, so you can either wait an indefinite time, or use some other approach (type class generation, scalafix rewrites, etc).

Answer (score 0):

Starting from Scala 3.3.0-RC2, there appeared macro annotations (implemented by Nicolas Stucki).

*Macro annotation (part 1)* https://github.com/lampepfl/dotty/pull/16392

*Macro annotations class modifications (part 2)* https://github.com/lampepfl/dotty/pull/16454

*Enable returning classes from MacroAnnotations (part 3)* https://github.com/lampepfl/dotty/pull/16534

**New definitions are not visible from outside the macro expansion.**

The macro annotation adding auxiliary constructor should be the following:

*build.sbt*

```
scalaVersion := "3.3.0-RC3"
```

```
import scala.annotation.{MacroAnnotation, experimental}
import scala.quoted.*

object Macros:
  @experimental
  class entity extends MacroAnnotation:
    def transform(using Quotes)(tree: quotes.reflect.Definition): List[quotes.reflect.Definition] =
      import quotes.reflect.*

      tree match
        case ClassDef(name, constr, parents, selfOpt, body) =>
          val constrSym = Symbol.newMethod(tree.symbol, "<init>", MethodType(Nil)(_ => Nil, _ => TypeRepr.of[Unit]))
          val constrDef = DefDef(constrSym, _ => Some(
            Apply(Select.unique(New(Inferred(tree.symbol.typeRef)), "<init>"), List('{0}.asTerm, '{null}.asTerm))
          ))

          val res = List(ClassDef.copy(tree)(name, constr, parents, selfOpt, body :+ constrDef))
          println(res.map(_.show))
          res

        case _ => report.errorAndAbort("@entity can annotate only classes")
```

```
import Macros.entity
import scala.annotation.experimental

object App:
  @entity @experimental
  class Student(val id: Long, val name: String)

//scalac: List(@scala.annotation.experimental @Macros.entity class Student(val id: scala.Long, val name: scala.Predef.String) {
//  def this() = new App.Student(0, null)
//})
```

[Macro Annotations in Scala 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67770927/macro-annotations-in-scala-3)

[How to generate a class in Dotty with macro?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59473523/how-to-generate-a-class-in-dotty-with-macro)

[Scala 3 macro to create enum](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69227772/scala-3-macro-to-create-enum)